# Splitting up jQuery to make it easier to understand

Tags: jquery

I have some jQuery code that I downloaded from a site and I want to make it easier to understand.

Can anyone help me get it to a state where I can remove parts of unused code?

```
(function(a){var A=function(s,v){var f=a.extend({},a.fn.nivoSlider.defaults,v),g={currentSlide:0,currentImage:"",totalSlides:0,randAnim:"",running:false,paused:false,stop:false},e=a(s);e.data("nivo:vars",g);e.css("position","relative");e.addClass("nivoSlider");var j=e.children();j.each(function(){var b=a(this),h="";if(!b.is("img")){if(b.is("a")){b.addClass("nivo-imageLink");h=b}b=b.find("img:first")}var c=b.width();if(c==0)c=b.attr("width");var o=b.height();if(o==0)o=b.attr("height");c>e.width()&&
e.width(c);o>e.height()&&e.height(o);h!=""&&h.css("display","none");b.css("display","none");g.totalSlides++});if(f.startSlide>0){if(f.startSlide>=g.totalSlides)f.startSlide=g.totalSlides-1;g.currentSlide=f.startSlide}g.currentImage=a(j[g.currentSlide]).is("img")?a(j[g.currentSlide]):a(j[g.currentSlide]).find("img:first");a(j[g.currentSlide]).is("a")&&a(j[g.currentSlide]).css("display","block");e.css("background",'url("'+g.currentImage.attr("src")+'") no-repeat');for(var k=0;k<f.slices;k++){var p=
Math.round(e.width()/f.slices);k==f.slices-1?e.append(a('<div class="nivo-slice"></div>').css({left:p*k+"px",width:e.width()-p*k+"px"})):e.append(a('<div class="nivo-slice"></div>').css({left:p*k+"px",width:p+"px"}))}e.append(a('<div class="nivo-caption"><p></p></div>').css({display:"none",opacity:f.captionOpacity}));if(g.currentImage.attr("title")!=""){k=g.currentImage.attr("title");if(k.substr(0,1)=="#")k=a(k).html();a(".nivo-caption p",e).html(k);a(".nivo-caption",e).fadeIn(f.animSpeed)}var l=
0;if(!f.manualAdvance&&j.length>1)l=setInterval(function(){r(e,j,f,false)},f.pauseTime);if(f.directionNav){e.append('<div class="nivo-directionNav"><a class="nivo-prevNav">Prev</a><a class="nivo-nextNav">Next</a></div>');if(f.directionNavHide){a(".nivo-directionNav",e).hide();e.hover(function(){a(".nivo-directionNav",e).show()},function(){a(".nivo-directionNav",e).hide()})}a("a.nivo-prevNav",e).live("click",function(){if(g.running)return false;clearInterval(l);l="";g.currentSlide-=2;r(e,j,f,"prev")});
a("a.nivo-nextNav",e).live("click",function(){if(g.running)return false;clearInterval(l);l="";r(e,j,f,"next")})}if(f.controlNav){p=a('<div class="nivo-controlNav"></div>');e.append(p);for(k=0;k<j.length;k++)if(f.controlNavThumbs){var t=j.eq(k);t.is("img")||(t=t.find("img:first"));f.controlNavThumbsFromRel?p.append('<a class="nivo-control" rel="'+k+'"><img src="'+t.attr("rel")+'" alt="" /></a>'):p.append('<a class="nivo-control" rel="'+k+'"><img src="'+t.attr("src").replace(f.controlNavThumbsSearch,
f.controlNavThumbsReplace)+'" alt="" /></a>')}else p.append('<a class="nivo-control" rel="'+k+'">'+(k+1)+"</a>");a(".nivo-controlNav a:eq("+g.currentSlide+")",e).addClass("active");a(".nivo-controlNav a",e).live("click",function(){if(g.running)return false;if(a(this).hasClass("active"))return false;clearInterval(l);l="";e.css("background",'url("'+g.currentImage.attr("src")+'") no-repeat');g.currentSlide=a(this).attr("rel")-1;r(e,j,f,"control")})}f.keyboardNav&&a(window).keypress(function(b){if(b.keyCode==
"37"){if(g.running)return false;clearInterval(l);l="";g.currentSlide-=2;r(e,j,f,"prev")}if(b.keyCode=="39"){if(g.running)return false;clearInterval(l);l="";r(e,j,f,"next")}});f.pauseOnHover&&e.hover(function(){g.paused=true;clearInterval(l);l=""},function(){g.paused=false;if(l==""&&!f.manualAdvance)l=setInterval(function(){r(e,j,f,false)},f.pauseTime)});e.bind("nivo:animFinished",function(){g.running=false;a(j).each(function(){a(this).is("a")&&a(this).css("display","none")});a(j[g.currentSlide]).is("a")&&
a(j[g.currentSlide]).css("display","block");if(l==""&&!g.paused&&!f.manualAdvance)l=setInterval(function(){r(e,j,f,false)},f.pauseTime);f.afterChange.call(this)});var w=function(b,h){var c=0;a(".nivo-slice",b).each(function(){var o=a(this),d=Math.round(b.width()/h.slices);c==h.slices-1?o.css("width",b.width()-d*c+"px"):o.css("width",d+"px");c++})},r=function(b,h,c,o){var d=b.data("nivo:vars");d&&d.currentSlide==d.totalSlides-1&&c.lastSlide.call(this);if((!d||d.stop)&&!o)return false;c.beforeChange.call(this);
if(o){o=="prev"&&b.css("background",'url("'+d.currentImage.attr("src")+'") no-repeat');o=="next"&&b.css("background",'url("'+d.currentImage.attr("src")+'") no-repeat')}else b.css("background",'url("'+d.currentImage.attr("src")+'") no-repeat');d.currentSlide++;if(d.currentSlide==d.totalSlides){d.currentSlide=0;c.slideshowEnd.call(this)}if(d.currentSlide<0)d.currentSlide=d.totalSlides-1;d.currentImage=a(h[d.currentSlide]).is("img")?a(h[d.currentSlide]):a(h[d.currentSlide]).find("img:first");if(c.controlNav){a(".nivo-controlNav a",
b).removeClass("active");a(".nivo-controlNav a:eq("+d.currentSlide+")",b).addClass("active")}if(d.currentImage.attr("title")!=""){var u=d.currentImage.attr("title");if(u.substr(0,1)=="#")u=a(u).html();a(".nivo-caption",b).css("display")=="block"?a(".nivo-caption p",b).fadeOut(c.animSpeed,function(){a(this).html(u);a(this).fadeIn(c.animSpeed)}):a(".nivo-caption p",b).html(u);a(".nivo-caption",b).fadeIn(c.animSpeed)}else a(".nivo-caption",b).fadeOut(c.animSpeed);var m=0;a(".nivo-slice",b).each(function(){var i=
Math.round(b.width()/c.slices);a(this).css({height:"0px",opacity:"0",background:'url("'+d.currentImage.attr("src")+'") no-repeat -'+(i+m*i-i)+"px 0%"});m++});if(c.effect=="random"){h=["sliceDownRight","sliceDownLeft","sliceUpRight","sliceUpLeft","sliceUpDown","sliceUpDownLeft","fold","fade","slideInRight","slideInLeft"];d.randAnim=h[Math.floor(Math.random()*(h.length+1))];if(d.randAnim==undefined)d.randAnim="fade"}if(c.effect.indexOf(",")!=-1){h=c.effect.split(",");d.randAnim=h[Math.floor(Math.random()*
h.length)];if(d.randAnim==undefined)d.randAnim="fade"}d.running=true;if(c.effect=="sliceDown"||c.effect=="sliceDownRight"||d.randAnim=="sliceDownRight"||c.effect=="sliceDownLeft"||d.randAnim=="sliceDownLeft"){var n=0;m=0;w(b,c);h=a(".nivo-slice",b);if(c.effect=="sliceDownLeft"||d.randAnim=="sliceDownLeft")h=a(".nivo-slice",b)._reverse();h.each(function(){var i=a(this);i.css({top:"0px"});m==c.slices-1?setTimeout(function(){i.animate({height:"100%",opacity:"1.0"},c.animSpeed,"",function(){b.trigger("nivo:animFinished")})},
100+n):setTimeout(function(){i.animate({height:"100%",opacity:"1.0"},c.animSpeed)},100+n);n+=50;m++})}else if(c.effect=="sliceUp"||c.effect=="sliceUpRight"||d.randAnim=="sliceUpRight"||c.effect=="sliceUpLeft"||d.randAnim=="sliceUpLeft"){m=n=0;w(b,c);h=a(".nivo-slice",b);if(c.effect=="sliceUpLeft"||d.randAnim=="sliceUpLeft")h=a(".nivo-slice",b)._reverse();h.each(function(){var i=a(this);i.css({bottom:"0px"});m==c.slices-1?setTimeout(function(){i.animate({height:"100%",opacity:"1.0"},c.animSpeed,"",
function(){b.trigger("nivo:animFinished")})},100+n):setTimeout(function(){i.animate({height:"100%",opacity:"1.0"},c.animSpeed)},100+n);n+=50;m++})}else if(c.effect=="sliceUpDown"||c.effect=="sliceUpDownRight"||d.randAnim=="sliceUpDown"||c.effect=="sliceUpDownLeft"||d.randAnim=="sliceUpDownLeft"){var x=m=n=0;w(b,c);h=a(".nivo-slice",b);if(c.effect=="sliceUpDownLeft"||d.randAnim=="sliceUpDownLeft")h=a(".nivo-slice",b)._reverse();h.each(function(){var i=a(this);if(m==0){i.css("top","0px");m++}else{i.css("bottom",
"0px");m=0}x==c.slices-1?setTimeout(function(){i.animate({height:"100%",opacity:"1.0"},c.animSpeed,"",function(){b.trigger("nivo:animFinished")})},100+n):setTimeout(function(){i.animate({height:"100%",opacity:"1.0"},c.animSpeed)},100+n);n+=50;x++})}else if(c.effect=="fold"||d.randAnim=="fold"){m=n=0;w(b,c);a(".nivo-slice",b).each(function(){var i=a(this),y=i.width();i.css({top:"0px",height:"100%",width:"0px"});m==c.slices-1?setTimeout(function(){i.animate({width:y,opacity:"1.0"},c.animSpeed,"",function(){b.trigger("nivo:animFinished")})},
100+n):setTimeout(function(){i.animate({width:y,opacity:"1.0"},c.animSpeed)},100+n);n+=50;m++})}else if(c.effect=="fade"||d.randAnim=="fade"){var q=a(".nivo-slice:first",b);q.css({height:"100%",width:b.width()+"px"});q.animate({opacity:"1.0"},c.animSpeed*2,"",function(){b.trigger("nivo:animFinished")})}else if(c.effect=="slideInRight"||d.randAnim=="slideInRight"){q=a(".nivo-slice:first",b);q.css({height:"100%",width:"0px",opacity:"1"});q.animate({width:b.width()+"px"},c.animSpeed*2,"",function(){b.trigger("nivo:animFinished")})}else if(c.effect==
"slideInLeft"||d.randAnim=="slideInLeft"){q=a(".nivo-slice:first",b);q.css({height:"100%",width:"0px",opacity:"1",left:"",right:"0px"});q.animate({width:b.width()+"px"},c.animSpeed*2,"",function(){q.css({left:"0px",right:""});b.trigger("nivo:animFinished")})}},z=function(b){this.console&&typeof console.log!="undefined"&&console.log(b)};this.stop=function(){if(!a(s).data("nivo:vars").stop){a(s).data("nivo:vars").stop=true;z("Stop Slider")}};this.start=function(){if(a(s).data("nivo:vars").stop){a(s).data("nivo:vars").stop=
false;z("Start Slider")}};f.afterLoad.call(this)};a.fn.nivoSlider=function(s){return this.each(function(){var v=a(this);if(!v.data("nivoslider")){var f=new A(this,s);v.data("nivoslider",f)}})};a.fn.nivoSlider.defaults={effect:"random",slices:15,animSpeed:500,pauseTime:3E3,startSlide:0,directionNav:true,directionNavHide:true,controlNav:true,controlNavThumbs:false,controlNavThumbsFromRel:false,controlNavThumbsSearch:".jpg",controlNavThumbsReplace:"_thumb.jpg",keyboardNav:true,pauseOnHover:true,manualAdvance:false,
captionOpacity:0.8,beforeChange:function(){},afterChange:function(){},slideshowEnd:function(){},lastSlide:function(){},afterLoad:function(){}};a.fn._reverse=[].reverse})(jQuery);
```

Comment: google helps... `javascript deobfuscate`...

Comment: I suggest you have a look at code that is not minified and has comments, e.g. [nivoslider@github](https://github.com/gilbitron/Nivo-Slider/blob/master/jquery.nivo.slider.js). After you have tried to understand the code, and can come up with more specific questions, people are more likely to (be able to) help.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing you could do with this is to run it through a [beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/).

```
(function (a) {
    var A = function (s, v) {
        var f = a.extend({}, a.fn.nivoSlider.defaults, v),
            g = {
                currentSlide: 0,
                currentImage: "",
                totalSlides: 0,
                randAnim: "",
                running: false,
                paused: false,
                stop: false
            },
            e = a(s);
        e.data("nivo:vars", g);
// etc...
```

It seems that it's the source code for nivoSlider. If you compare the above beautified code with the [nivoSlider source code](https://github.com/gilbitron/Nivo-Slider/blob/master/jquery.nivo.slider.js) others have posted you can see the similarity.

Comment: Thanks. I did this but for some reason the code doesn't work in this form. Why could this be? Sorry if I sound stupid but I don't work with jQuery.

Comment: @user612134: I didn't post the entire code, only the first few lines.

Comment: @user The beautifier might be writing out invalid code. Sometimes minifiers do some really serious work to compress code down. Since we know where to find the original, unminified version of this codebase, you should probably just go with that. ;)

Answer (score 3):

That is minified code.  It's very hard to reread due to the renaming of variables.  If you just want to read the code itself, paste it into http://www.jsbeautifier.com/

Download your uncompressed code here:
http://nivo.dev7studios.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use JS Beautifier to make the code readable http://jsbeautifier.org/

..then you can easily edit the code and remove unused code as you wish.

[Other useful tools](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/super-useful-online-tools-to-make-javascript-development-easier)

Answer (score -1):

For the actual jQuery library (the code you included does not appear to be the actual library), download the un-minified version.. it will make a lot more sense

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js

As for the code your're showing, you can use a beautifier as other answers have pointed out.

Comment: It appears that the JS is *minified*. Wouldn't compression be different?

Comment: If you looked at the code you'd notice it isn't the jQuery library, so no, downloading jQuery won't help him much.

Comment: I don't think that that's the actual jQuery library (in compressed form), just code using it.

Comment: wow... lots of quick down-votes... little harsh... but I guess that's what I get for not parsing minified code very fast :)

Comment: If you look at the minified code you can see it says 'nivo' all over the place. Before recommending downloading jQuery you might have wanted to to do a bit of due diligence and make sure that is what the code he shared was. Alternatively, had you phrased your original question a little more gently, perhaps people would have been more gentle on you. Friendliness begets friendliness.

Comment: yep, I totally agree, my mistake and deserve the down votes... what can I say :)